# Why does the pandas scatterplot method raise a warning?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code

```
mall_customers_info.plot.scatter(x='Age',
                                 y='Annual_Income',
                                 c='Spending Score (1-100)',
                                 colormap='viridis',
                                 figsize=(10, 8));
```

Warning Messages

> /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/tools.py:298: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   The rowNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start instead.
>     layout[ax.rowNum, ax.colNum] = ax.get_visible()
>   /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/tools.py:298: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   The colNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start instead.
>     layout[ax.rowNum, ax.colNum] = ax.get_visible()
>   /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/tools.py:304: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   The rowNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start instead.
>     if not layout[ax.rowNum + 1, ax.colNum]:
>   /Users/georgeng/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/tools.py:304: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   The colNum attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.2 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().colspan.start instead.
>     if not layout[ax.rowNum + 1, ax.colNum]:

Does anyone have ideas on how to use ax.get_subplotspec().rowspan.start instead as given in the warning?

Thanks for all your help
George

Comment: You're using pandas to plot your dataframe. Interally, pandas is using a matplotlib API that is scheduled for deprecation. There's nothing you can or need to do about that

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 8))

mall_customers_info.plot.scatter(x='Age',
                                 y='Annual_Income',
                                 c='Spending Score (1-100)',
                                 colormap='viridis',
                                 ax=ax);
```

Versions

```py
In [16]: matplotlib.__version__                                                                                                                                                  
Out[16]: '3.1.3'

In [17]: pd.__version__                                                                                                                                                          
Out[17]: '1.0.3'
```

Comment: The OP is using a matplotlib version that is at least version 3.2.